# How to implement domain entities in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, domain-driven-design, dto, data-class

Based on the [official documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html) and this [detekt rule](https://arturbosch.github.io/detekt/style.html#dataclasscontainsfunctions) my understanding is that data classes should rather be used as DTOs and should not contain any behavior/logic.

However, for my domain entities (which contain both data and behavior) I'd still like to have features like automatic `toString`, `equals` and destructuring declarations.

I can easily achieve this with data classes, but based on the above that seems to be semantically incorrect:

```kotlin
data class Person(
    private var name: String,
    val age: Int
) {
    fun isAdult() = age >= 18

    fun changeName(newName: String) {
        this.name = newName
    }
}
```

Is it inherently wrong to use data class for this purpose? Is there another way to keep these features but be semantically correct at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two important topics:

**Immutability**

I would embrace immutability and not provide any mutation method in the domain classes. You can use `copy` method to create new instance with different immutable properties.

**Identity**

A Data class uses all properties declared in the constructor in the equals method. It means it is a value class, that is, it doesn't have identity. It is a value like Point(x,y). Two instances Point(1,2) and Point(1,2) are indistinguishable. They are the same if all of their properties are the same.

**Conclusion**

Use a regular `class` for a domain entity like an *User*. Use the properties which define the identity of your entity to implement `equals`, `hashcode`, etc. Use a `data class` for a domain value like an *Address*. It is fine for a data class to have functions as long as they are mutation free.

In your case I would implement something like that:

```
data class Address(val streetName: String)

class Person(
    val id: Int,
    val name: String,
    val age: Int,
    val address: Address
) {
    fun isAdult() = age >= 18

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (this === other) return true
        if (javaClass != other?.javaClass) return false

        other as Person

        if (id != other.id) return false

        return true
    }

    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        return id
    }

    fun copy(
        id: Int = this.id, 
        name: String = this.name, 
        age: Int = this.age,
        address: Address = this.address) = Person(id, name, age, address)

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "Person(id=$id, name='$name', age=$age, address=$address)"
    }
}


fun main() {
    val personA = Person(123312, "Person A", 17, Address("Street 1"))
    println(personA.isAdult())
    println(personA.age)

    val olderPersonA = personA.copy(age = 18)
    println(olderPersonA.isAdult())
    println(olderPersonA.age)
}
```

**EDIT:** As you said, there is the option of using a data class and only override equals and hashcode, but I'm no sure if it is semantically correct. Comments on that are appreciated.

```
data class Person(
    val id: Int,
    val name: String,
    val age: Int,
    val address: Address
) {
    fun isAdult() = age >= 18

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (this === other) return true
        if (javaClass != other?.javaClass) return false

        other as Person

        if (id != other.id) return false

        return true
    }

    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        return id
    }
}
```

Comment: my concern is that boilerplate code is coming back and every time I add a new field I need to regenerate toString...
It just seems more simple to have a data class and only override equals and hashCode

Comment: You can do it also. But I think you might end up with a data class that is semantically different from what a data class means. But it can be only my opinion. I'm not sure if my definition of a data class is correct.